R: Default argument scoping
A colleague of mine ran into an interesting problem with R. We managed to work around it but want to understand how R (internally) handles the scoping of default arguments for user-defined functions. Here is the code, and the problem:
a <- 4

funa <- function(a = a) { print(a) }
funb <- function(b = a) { print(b) }

funa(a)  # Prints 4
funb(a)  # Prints 4
funb()   # Prints 4
funa()   # Error: object 'a' not found

So apparently, when default arguments have the same keyword as the name of the variable, something goes wrong. I would like to understand how R finds default arguments upon first defining the function, what appears to create this problem, because this solves it:
funa <- function(a = get("a", envir = .GlobalEnv)) { print(a) }

Edit: this question was closed but I don’t think the linked answers help me understand how R internally handles this. I would appreciate an explanation if anyone is interested in detailing this out for me. :)

Default arguments are resolved when the function runs in the function scope. They are not part of the closure when the function is created. Parameters will shadow variables contained in the lexical scope. This allows you to have things like func <- function(a, b = a) { print(paste(a,b)) }; func(6)

Not sure how that problem does not occur for funcb then…

Because funcb doesn't shadow the a variable. So when b is set to a, the a value is free and is resolved in the lexical scope. Just the same way that funcd <- function() print(a) would work.

So since a <- 4; funca <- function(a=a){ print("Hello") } does not give an error, am I right to assume that the parameter a is still recursively defined due to shadowing, even though it's not used?

Yes. It's a promise that's never evaluated so not a problem. It's not really recursive, it's just that in the function environment a is a defined but is still in the lazy state. You only have a problem when you try to evaluate it in that function environment. It's no longer a free variable but it's unable to be resolved.

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish exactly, but if you want a function with a default value from a specific environment, you probably want to create a closure.
